# How do I change the position of an NSButton?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, appkit

I'm currently using Swift on Xcode 10.3. I am creating a Cocoa Application for MacOS using AppKit, if that helps. And I'm fairly new to the Swift programming language, so please try and simplify explanations wherever possible.

**I want to know how to change the x and y position of an NSButton through code, so that an event (such as mouseEntered) causes it to move.**

I want to do this programmatically, not using the storyboard or anything.

Comment: You could use `setFrame` but view geometry math is pretty annoying in macOS. You are encouraged to use Auto Layout and modify constraints.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can change the position of an `NSView` programmatically.  I'm not a storyboard expert, but if I understand correctly they cannot be used to dynamically change positions. So, you must write some code to do what you want.

If your views are being laid out using AutoLayout, you can adjust the `constant` field of your `NSLayoutConstraint` objects. Or, you can also just create/remove constraints to achieve the effect you are after.

In a non-AutoLayout layout, you'll have to change the `origin` property of the view's `frame`. See the documentation on this one [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483713-frame).

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm pretty sure that I'm using AutoLayout but I have almost no clue how to use it. Could you please explain how to do that?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really set up to answer that kind of question. AutoLayout is a big topic. Luckily, there are a huge number of articles posted online about it! Just do some searching and you'll find what you need. Here's a getting started article by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html